# Easiest way to compile IronPython from the command line?

Tags: nant, ironpython

I've just started looking at IronPython, and I was hoping to build EXEs using NAnt.  I'm not seeing much info on this... is it possible?  Or, if not, is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build IronPython itself, use msbuild as recommended by Curt.

If you want to build IronPython program, use `IronPython\Tools\Scripts\pyc.py`, e.g.:

```
ipy.exe pyc.py /main:Program.py Form.py /target:winexe
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, all C# projects and solutions can be built from the command line with msbuild.

[MSBuild Command Line Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)